# How can I manage protected routes with firebase and react-context? Protected route gets stuck in the loading state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, react-context

I am writing a web Application in React with Typescript and Firebase. I am trying to manage the authentication using context but something is wrong with my protected route component.

So far my AuthContext looks like this:

```
interface AuthState {
  currentUser: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
  logout: () => Promise<void>;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthState>({} as AuthState);

interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const logout = async () => {
    await signOut(auth);
    setCurrentUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [currentUser]);

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({ currentUser, loading, logout }),
    [currentUser, loading]
  );

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

And this is the protected route component:

```
interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export const Protected = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { currentUser, loading } = useAuth();

  if (loading) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }

  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

The problem is that when I try to access a route that is protected, I don't get redirected to the login page, instead I get stuck with the "loading" message.

This is the behavior:

[image]

My intuition is that the problem comes from the useEffect from the AuthContext.

When I tried to move the `setLoading(false)` right after the if statement block, the unauthorized redirect worked but then I faced another error.

When I try to perform a login, the `Protected` component acts like the `currentUser` is null even if right after the login call I change the URL to `/profile` page it will work as expected. I think that happens because the `setCurrentUser` isn't finished when the `Protected` checks the user state.

Below is the second variant of my useEffect hook from AuthContext and a visual demo of what is happening.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [currentUser]);
```

[image]

How can I solve these 2 errors? What is the best way to manage states in `AuthContext`? How can I implement the `Protected` component to redirect the user when is unauthorized and handle the `loading` case at the same time?

Thank you!